# Formulas are flickering in the preview as I type

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

When I typing my post MathJax re-render the preview after each key press, leading to an annoying flicker in the preview area as I'm typing. When there are lots of formulas it also slows down the entire thing making my characters appear in the editing window with a noticeable delay as it renders. My computer isn't a recent fast one so it's quite annoying when my post contains lots of formulas.

Is it possible to add some delay so it re-renders it let's say a second after the last keypress?

EDIT:

Operating system: Linux

Results of `uname -a`:

`Linux calmarius-desktop 3.2.0-80-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 23 17:11:03 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

The browser is Google Chrome 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit) without addons.

Comment: This annoys me too. I just scroll the page to put the edit window at the bottom and hide the preview.

Comment: @JohnRennie My current workaround is not adding the $'s till I done with the post.

Comment: You might be interested in the [math.se] meta posts: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2558/ and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/689

Comment: There *should* be a delay by default (of 5 sec); you may want to display your OS & Browser information for better diagnosis.

Comment: This has been [a problem at least once before](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/814/). But I thought it had been dealt with.

Comment: I observe the same behaviour, on essentially the same setup. And I also find it annoying.

Comment: I like seeing how my changes instantly affect the rendering. But maybe I'm just the odd man out on this

Comment: I'm running Mint, using Firefox and do not have any flickering effects (though it's not a 5 sec delay, maybe 1-2). Perhaps we should chalk it up to Chrome sucking as a browser, given its [other issue(s?)](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/the-site-toolbar-looks-broken-in-chrome-how-can-i-fix-it)?

Comment: I see this behavior on Firefox on both Windows and MacOS.

Comment: I see this behavior *all the time* and while I like the instant updating, because it points out errors, I wish it happened a bit less often, as it is a tad disorienting (I often look at the preview and actual typing equally while I'm writing).